# Simplest way to use jQuery to access an input via a label jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Let's say that you have the following code:

```
<input name="my-input' id="my-input-id" />
<label for="my-input-id">
```

There's a click event attached to the label, like so:

```
$("label[for='my-input-id']").click( function() {
    var myLabel = $(this);
}
```

What's the easiest/simplest way to get a jQuery object of the input via the myLabel jQuery object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your case

```
$("label[for='my-input-id']").click( function() {
    var myLabel = $(this);
    var input = $('#' + myLabel.attr('for'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("label[for='my-input-id']").click(function() {
  var input = $('#' + this.htmlFor);
  input.css('outline','1px solid red');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="my-input" id="my-input-id" />
<label for="my-input-id">a</label>
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("label[for='my-input-id']").click( function() {
    var myLabel = $(this);
    var input = $('input[id=' + myLabel.attr('for') + ']');
}
```

Comment: label `for` represents `id` not `name`.

Answer (score 0):

If input will be immediately in preceding position to label i.e myLabel in this case then you can also use JQuery .prev() that is Traversing. Have a look in below js code

```
$("label[for='my-input-id']").click( function() {
  var myLabel = $(this);
  var input = $(this).prev();
}
```